# Getting com.android.volley.ServerError using the Volley library. What are some possible causes?

Tags: android, android-volley

When I make a request in Volley, I'm receiving `com.android.volley.ServerError` and response code 400.

I'm doing something like this (generic example code):

```java
final String param1 = "...";
final String param2 = "...";
// etc. 

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, API_URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("PARAM_1", param1);
        params.put("PARAM_2",password);
        return params;
    }

};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

What are possible causes for this?

Comment: I'd suggest capturing the request on the wire with tcpdump or wireshark and compare that with a working request from a browser or Postman.

Comment: Could also be something wrong with your php script as I have experienced.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, but then I realized that my URL wasn't using HTTPS, it was HTTP. Once I switched to HTTPS, it worked perfectly. Please double-check to ensure you don't have the same oversight.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. It drained my entire day. Finally, I Found the tiny error, which was that I was passing a null value in parameters.

Check if you are passing a null value to the server in getParams() or your JSON Object. If yes, that may be the problem.

Comment: In case that helps someone:
You don't want to pass any params? --> Set it to null but do NOT use an empty HashMap<String, String> as second argument E.g. this works JsonObjectRequest(YOUR_URL, null, ...)

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, but then I realized that my URL wasn't using HTTPS; it was HTTP. Once I switched to HTTPS, it worked perfectly. Please double-check to ensure you don't have the same oversight

Answer (score 7):

In below method

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
```

add this line:-

```
error.printStackTrace()
```

You will get all stack trace which gives you the actual error. I have also get this error but in my case it is actually TimeoutException.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, but then I realized that my URL wasn't using HTTPS; it was HTTP. Once I switched to HTTPS, it worked perfectly. Please double-check to ensure you don't have the same oversight

Answer (score 3):

Response Code 400 means Bad Request.

Some reasons for that.

1. There might be issue in Request method. Is it GET or POST?
2. API might be expecting Authorization Header.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue, but then I realized that my URL wasn't using HTTPS; it was HTTP. Once I switched to HTTPS, it worked perfectly. Please double-check to ensure you don't have the same oversight

Answer (score 1):

This error can mean BAD REQUEST, check the headers you are sending. Overring the getHeaders() method you can send the right headers.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return (headers != null || headers.isEmpty()) ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}
```

Also, usually the WebServices need application/json headers, as follow:

```
headers.put("Accept","application/json");
headers.put("Content-Type","application/json");
```

Answer (score 1):

Some possible causes of this error:

1. Wrong URL.  Check your URL for any errors.
2. Missing parameters, any parameters having null value or you are missing any parameter.
3. Watch for the Keys defined in the params, it should match with those of APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to tell your server that send the response with the code 200, volley checks for this codes.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your parameters (there should be no null parameter). If it's ok then If you are using `JSONObjectRequest` then remove `Request.Method.GET` as per new google policy.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, but then I realized that my URL wasn't using HTTPS; it was HTTP. Once I switched to HTTPS, it worked perfectly. Please double-check to ensure you don't have the same oversight